# Question on STL internals

Tags: c++, optimization, stl, io, mmap

I am currently writing some abstractions on IO for binary data. At this point I am currently not sure on how well the STL performs on some of these tasks. For example I have a lot of stuff I can encode binary to either char * or std::vector. For now whenever I have an object of this kind of byte type I either just write it using ostream::write() or do a std::copy on the array to a ostream_iterater on the stream. Now I was wondering, what the copy will do internally.

From what I heard, the STL is allowed to optimize anything. For example in Theory a copy of two vectors storing chars using std::copy should not copy these chars byte by byte slowly but rather use system primitives for copying chuncks of data, where available. How is this done internally.

The reason I am asking this, is because I am now trying to switch the file over to mmaped memory instead of std::ostreams. This means, that writing the char* data will be really simple, but writing vectors will be byte by byte. What would I have to provide for in my class for the STL to optimize the copying away (probably using memcpy)? I am guessing I need the right kind of iterators, but what do they need, so the STL will know it can just memcopy instead of walking them.

I know this is asking a lot of stuff I should not normally care about (principle of encapsulation is a great thing usually). And of course I know of Knuths rule of optimization, that is why I am caring about the automatic optimization facilities of the STL.

Comment: Like you say, we don't know. The vector::iterator just stores a pointer inside, so the compiler could very well optimize the copy. You have to try it out, and see if it works for you and your compiler.

Comment: Why would the vector be copied byte by byte? I don't really see the connection to `std::copy`. You can use `std::copy` on a char array just as well as on a vector. Apart from the obvious advice to "measure it yourself", show us some code. We don't know what is in your vector, or how it is copied, so telling you *how fast* it is copied is impossible.

Comment: The reason I am thinking the Vector would be copied in a byte by byte way is, because I would need to pass the std::copy algorithm a custom iterator to the mmaped memory region. From this iterator the STL would then have to infer that it can optimize away the loop from the reference implementation. But what information is it using for this inference and how do I provide it?

Comment: This “custom iterator” could just be a `char*`, right? And if your implementation of the STL (please, not “the STL”) has specializations for copying to `char*`, then those would obviously apply. (You are also allowed to specialize `std::copy` yourself, as long as you follow the one definition rule.)

Comment: @Christopher Yeah, just realized this myself a few minutes ago, that I will simplify my life a lot if I just do a `typedef char * iterator` in my buffer class. Also thanks for the hint on specializing `std::copy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iostream` is for *formatted* (ie. text) IO *only*. If you want binary IO, you have to use `streambuf` classes.

Also, iostreams have the reputation of being slow (for various reasons, and your mileage will vary).

Iostreams use streambuf internally, which adds a layer of indirection, and provides you with automatic buffering. If you need reasonable binary IO throughput, you may want to use streambuf derived classes directly (like `fstreambuf`) and benchmark it (and disable [synchronization with stdio](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/sync_with_stdio/)).

Or you can directly use `mmap` or `write`. Those functions are quite simple to use, and it should be easy to write your own classes around it.

Oh, and don't assume anything on what the standard library does. If you want to know more about how it does things internally, check the sources of eg. the GNU implementation.

Comment: Ok, the hint to the streambuf seems very goog. However I cannot find a reference to the fstreambuf at my [usual place of reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/streambuf/). Do you have any link to a place, where I can get more information?

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't sure how well the STL performs, there is no substitute for testing. Time how long it takes to std::copy a chunk of data lots of times, and how long it takes to copy the same amount of data using memcopy, and compare.

Doing these tests yourself will be far more instructive than worrying about STL optimisation.

Comment: Nitpick: Testing can only show you how well the implementation of the STL you have performs, in connection with the compiler you have, and those parameters can change with the next compiler upgrade. So can the optimization of your own code. Other than that, I agree with what you said.

Comment: Very true. Of course, that strengthens the point; Testing would be the only way to determine how the compiler upgrade had affected performance. I thought that the OP might be looking for a straightforward "STL (is too slow|fast enough) for your task", and any answer other than "test it" might be invalidated by a compiler or STL change.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear what you're asking. You mention vectors, `std::copy`, `char*` and memory-mapped files, but there's no obvious connection between them. Show us some code, or describe what you're trying to do, and with what kind of data types.

But a common optimization in STL implementations is to use `memcpy` or a similar raw memory copying mechanism as long as the object type you're copying is POD. So assuming this optimization exists in your STL implementation, all you have to do is make sure the objects you're copying are POD types.

But as previously mentioned, the only way to get reliable information about performance is to profile/measure/benchmark it yourself.